# Firestore rules stop listener

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

For my Firebase project I have created following Firestore rule:

```
 match /games/{gameDoc=**} {
        allow read, write: if resource.data.playerOne == request.auth.uid 
        || resource.data.playerTwo == request.auth.uid;
}
```

The rule works as intended, however my problem is that I set up listeners to documents that are affected by these rules. When a document is changed or created, the listener is called but when a document is deleted, the listener is not triggered. As far as I understand, the problem derives from the fact that after the delete operation there is no playerOne or playerTwo field, therefore the rules reject to notify the listeners. Is there any way around this?

**EDIT:**

Listener on Client-Side (Unity):

```
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("games").Document(game.gameID)
docRef.Listen(snapshot => {
    Debug.Log("Game data changed");

    if(snapshot.ToDictionary() == null) // Game got deleted
    {
        dataManager.gameList.Remove(dataManager.gameList.Find(g => g.gameID == snapshot.Id));
    } else
    {
        OnGameDataChanged(snapshot.ToDictionary());
    }
    // Update UI
    FindObjectOfType<GUIManager>().gameListGUI.DisplayGames();
});
```

When I change the rules to true, the listener is notified.

Comment: Can you show the client side code? Fyi, this rule cannot work for a create as `resource.data` does not already exist then

Comment: I added the client side code. Yes thats true, when creating a new game I have to fetch that game document rather than receiving it from the listener

Comment: How is `docRef` initialized?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen             DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("games").Document(game.gameID);
I ended up allowing everyone to read from my game collection and restricted the access for write operations

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect the deletions you have to use the `change.ChangeType` object as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#unity_4). And you’ll be able to get the data of the deleted doc.

```
 Query query = db.Collection("...").WhereEqualTo(...);

 ListenerRegistration listener = query.Listen(snapshot =>
        {
            foreach (DocumentChange change in snapshot.GetChanges())
            {
                if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Added)
                {
                    Debug.Log(String.Format("New: {0}", change.Document.Id));
                }
                else if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Modified)
                {
                    Debug.Log(String.Format("Modified: {0}", change.Document.Id));
                }
                else if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Removed)
                {
                    Debug.Log(String.Format("Deleted: {0}", change.Document.Id));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, there is an important element to take into account: [Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters). So your query must match your security rule.

---

Also, as mentioned by l1b3rty in his comment, when writing data, the `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document. See [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).

Comment: I have already considered using different granular rules, but the problem is that I dont want a specfic rule for the deletion case but rather have access to the document fields before the delete operation was executed. It comes down to the read rule => game-document is deleted (let's say everyone is allowed to delete a document), now playerOne and playerTwo who have set a listener to that document are not allowed to READ this document because the fields that I specified in my rules are not existing anymmore.

Comment: Ok, I understand better and I'm going to adapt my answer.